# How to display EPPlus package in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, epplus

I have created an excel package using EPPlus, however instead of downloading as an excel file, I want to see the contents of that package in an asp.net page.

Comment: What is the content of the excelfile? If it's tabular data you could use a `GridView` otherwise a more flexible control like `Repeater`. However, i would use the datasource of the (newly) created excel file as datasource for the [databound webcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of the excel file directly.

Comment: It is randomly created report, something like an agreement, where there are some images, and some randomly filled cells, it is not tabular thus it is not symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to display as a PDF, in which case you'd need a converter. Someone else had that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512036/generate-a-pdf-report-from-a-generated-excel-file-epplus-library?rq=1).

Otherwise, since the fields aren't symmetric, you would have to create a custom aspx template deigned to pick up the fields and display them in the right areas, or maybe create a table grid and fill the empty excel cells with empty values in the generated table.